# Facing problems aligning my form on the center of the screen am using tailwind CSS

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I have tried justify-content and align-items but i think im using them incorectly because Login text is being aligned to the center of the screen but the form stays on the left side of the page ive tried everything can youkindly assist4

my code

```
 <div class="text-center text-black text-lg font-mono decoration-2">
        <h1>
            Login
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full max-w-xs flex flex-col justify-center items-center ">

    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" class="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 ">
        @csrf

        
    

        <!-- Email Address -->
        <div class="">
            <x-input-label for="email" :value="__('Email')" />
            <x-text-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" :value="old('email')" required autofocus />
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('email')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>



        <!-- Password -->
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-input-label for="password" :value="__('Password')" />

            <x-text-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full"
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            required autocomplete="current-password" />

            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <!-- Remember Me -->
        <div class="block mt-4">
            <label for="remember_me" class="inline-flex items-center">
                <input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" class="rounded dark:bg-gray-900 border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-700 text-indigo-600 shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 dark:focus:ring-indigo-600 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800" name="remember">
                <span class="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">{{ __('Remember me') }}</span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
            @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-gray-100 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                    {{ __('Forgot your password?') }}
                </a>
            @endif

            <x-primary-button class="ml-3">
                {{ __('Log in') }}
            </x-primary-button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you put this on codesanbox or Codepen? We don't know the JS and CSS files that you included in this page and so it's very hard to help you out

Comment: If all you want is to center the form then you just need to add `mx-auto` to its parent div where `max-w-xs` is.